# JSF Converter warning

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, converters

From my xhtml file:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{newPostForm.post.body}">
     <f:converter converterId="NL2BRConverter" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

From my java file:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)
public class NL2BRConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\r\n+", "<br />");
    //return str.replaceAll("\r\n+", "&#13");
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, Object obj) {
    return obj.toString();
}
```

}

Eclipse is giving me a warning in my xhtml file that *'NL2BRConverter' converterID is not registered.*

I've tried replacing the converter annotation with

```
@FacesConverter("NL2BRConverter")
```

but the error persists. Is this not sufficient to register a converter in JSF2.0 ?

Currently if I used the full class name "com.tracker.converter.NL2BRConverter" as the annotated name and the converterID in my XHTML files, it works. I still get that warning however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `<f:converter>` because your converter is already explicitly been declared by `forClass=String.class` to run on every `String` input type.

If your *actual* intent is to declare it explicitly for specific input fields in the view yourself, then you should instead be using

```
@FacesConverter(value="NL2BRConverter")
```

Then you can use

```
<f:converter converterId="NL2BRConverter" />
```

Comment: Excellent, to make sure I understand... using the annotation @FacesConverter(forClass=String.class) would cause this converter to be run whether I specify a converter or not in my view ?

Comment: It's not specifically the annotation, but the `forClass` argument which causes it to run on *every* property which is of `String` type. This is particularly useful for non-standard types like `Person` and so on. It's only a bit odd for `String` :)

Comment: I've been playing around with using a converter for all my String input/output. I can convert inputs with no problem, but the converter is ignored for output. Using the same converter, but specifying it by name works with no problem. Thoughts ? Should this be a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

While for this case you don't need to specify a converter in xhtml, the fact that you did this shouldn't cause a warning to display in Eclipse.  This is actually a bug in Eclipse.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357885 for more information.  I don't know of a way to hide this specific warning in Eclipse.