# Eclipse giving warning "converter id not registered" on custom converter

Tags: jsf-2, converters

I'm working with JSF 2 and JBoss EL (jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar). I'm having trouble getting a custom converter to work in a situation where I want to explicitly declare the converter along side the component in my xhtml page. I know there are tons of examples of this on the web already, and I've reviewed a good deal of them (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135867/jsf-converter-warning)) with no luck, which makes this problem especially frustrating. Also, I've implemented a custom converter using the `forClass` element of the `FacesConverter` annotation, and it works. I've done things the same way for the explicitly declared converter, except for using the `forClass` element. Instead, I'm using the `value` element or none at all.

I've tried (seemingly) all combinations of annotations: with and without the `value` element, using simple class name and fully qualified class name, uppercase first letter and lowercase first letter, and using the `converter` attribute and the `<f:converter>` tag. From what I've read, some of those things shouldn't make a difference one way or the other, but I tried them for lack of knowing what else to do. Eclipse keeps warning me that the "converter id is not registered." I run it anyway (because I've seen other situations where Eclipse gave an error, but there wasn't one in reality), but it throws a `NullPointerException`. Why is this not working? Here's one version of my code:

#### Converter class

```
@FacesConverter(value = "MyConverter")
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
    ...
}
```

#### XHTML page

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.myProperty}"
                  layout="pageDirection"
                  required="true"
                  requiredMessage="#{myBean.requiredMessage}"
                  converter="MyConverter"
                  id="#{myBean.myPropertyId}" >

    <!-- OTHER THINGS I'VE TRIED -->
    <!-- <f:converter converterId="MyConverter" /> -->
    <!-- <f:converter converterId="myConverter" /> -->
    <!-- <f:converter converterId="myPackage.MyConverter" /> -->

    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myPropertyOptions}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

One thing I'm unsure about, and I'm not sure whether it makes a difference for my issue, is whether I should or should not add `@ManagedBean` and `@ApplicationScoped` to these converters. I've seen other questions about this on SO, but I still don't have a clear vision of what is absolutely necessary, what is good practice, and what shouldn't be done. This particular converter is stateless, so I'm not trying to determine which scope to use, but rather whether to decalare one at all (same for declaring `@ManagedBean`). I've also tried removing one or both of these annotations, but it didn't fix it. At this point, I feel like I'm just stabbing in the dark.

**EDIT**
In case it helps, here's the stack trace after trying to run it:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRadioRendererBase.renderGroupOrItemRadio(HtmlRadioRendererBase.java:213)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRadioRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlRadioRendererBase.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:543)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:315)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:150)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:618)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:614)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1159)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: As to your converter registration, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183176/jsf-converter-for-selectonemenu/18187373#18187373 As to the NPE, did you read the MyFaces source code on that line? It hints that the converter returned `null`. As to Eclipse warning, that's a completely different problem (outdated development environment).

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the response. I checked out the link. I've removed the `@ManagedBean` and `@ApplicationScoped` annotations, and kept the `@FacesConverter(value = "MyConverter")`. So, the code I posted, `converter="MyConverter"` should work, right? From your comment, it sounds like the converter was already being invoked, but returning a null value. I guess the outdated dev env was just confusing me, making me think the error was there without investigating the stack trace better. Going to check that out now.

Comment: Just check the MyFaces source in your IDE. Or if you don't have it for some unclear reason, check [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.1.1/org/apache/myfaces/shared_impl/renderkit/html/HtmlRadioRendererBase.java#213). Only thing which can cause a NPE at line 213 is a null `itemStrValue`. In other words, `Converter#getAsString()` returned `null`.

Comment: @BalusC, I checked the MyFaces source and reviewed my code. And, yes, it looks like `getAsString` returned `null`, but it was supposed because `myBean.myProperty == null`. The first thing the converter did was `if (!(obj instanceof Integer)) return null;`. Since `((obj = null) instanceof Integer) == false` it rightly returned `null`. Digging deeper, I saw that `RendererUtils#getConvertedStringValue` never returns `null` if `converter == null`. I changed my converter to `if (!(obj instanceof Integer)) return "";` and the page now loads. Thanks for nudging me in the right direction!